# Windows 10: Is it normal for the system clock to stop during sleep?

Tags: bsod, time

1. Windows 10 goes into sleep when I close the lid at 10:46pm.
2. At 8:06am I wake the computer up, but the wake up time, per event log, is 9 seconds after it went to sleep (both in the event log viewer line and inside the details of the event)
3. System clock then resyncs with the hardware clock, it was off for the amount of hrs the system was asleep.

**Is this normal behavior?** I am trying to rule out this as the cause of the BSOD mentioned below.

UPDATE: This laptop is less than 1 year old, so I don't think the CMOS battery is low. Sure, I could have gotten a bad battery, but that would cause the HW clock to drift, not the system clock.

Then the computer crashes a bit later and then it restarts (plenty of correctly timed event log entries in between), but showing wrong clock time inside the entry details (and correct time in the event log viewer window): "The previous system shutdown at 10:35:16 PM on ‎6/‎29/‎2017 was unexpected." The BSOD was around 8:08.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
Date:          2017-06-30 08:06:26 AM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2017‎-‎06‎-‎30T05:46:04.542174700Z
Wake Time: ‎2017‎-‎06‎-‎30T15:06:25.350267000Z

Wake Source: Device -Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter" Guid="{CDC05E28-C449-49C6-B9D2-88CF761644DF}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T15:06:26.918654100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22414</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{297A7523-4DAA-4F2F-B986-85E257766E56}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="4832" ThreadID="8424" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security UserID="SID" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SleepTime">2017-06-30T05:46:04.542174700Z</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTime">2017-06-30T15:06:25.350267000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SleepDuration">1451</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeDuration">4849</Data>
    <Data Name="DriverInitDuration">4211</Data>
    <Data Name="BiosInitDuration">699</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberWriteDuration">0</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberReadDuration">0</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberPagesWritten">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Attributes">33574956</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeSourceType">5</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeSourceTextLength">61</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeSourceText">Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerOwnerLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerContextLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="NoMultiStageResumeReason">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerOwner">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerContext">
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          2017-06-30 08:06:20 AM
Event ID:      130
Task Category: (33)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
Firmware S3 times. SuspendStart: 36729617, SuspendEnd: 36729624
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>130</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>33</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T15:06:20.707483500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22413</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="16764" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SuspendStart">36729617</Data>
    <Data Name="SuspendEnd">36729624</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          2017-06-30 08:06:20 AM
Event ID:      131
Task Category: (33)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 2, FullResume: 533, AverageResume: 534
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>131</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>33</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T15:06:20.707481900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22412</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="16764" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ResumeCount">2</Data>
    <Data Name="FullResume">533</Data>
    <Data Name="AverageResume">534</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General
Date:          2017-06-30 08:06:20 AM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: (5)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Time
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎06‎-‎30T15:06:20.500000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎06‎-‎30T05:46:14.018104300Z.

Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" Guid="{A68CA8B7-004F-D7B6-A698-07E2DE0F1F5D}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>5</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T15:06:20.500040300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22411</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="16764" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="NewTime">2017-06-30T15:06:20.500000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="OldTime">2017-06-30T05:46:14.018104300Z</Data>
    <Data Name="Reason">2</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          2017-06-29 10:46:14 PM
Event ID:      107
Task Category: (102)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(64),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
The system has resumed from sleep.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>107</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>102</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000444</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T05:46:14.017891800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22410</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="16764" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeFromState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="ProgrammedWakeTimeAc">2017-07-02T17:46:05.993264500Z</Data>
    <Data Name="ProgrammedWakeTimeDc">2017-07-02T17:46:05.993264500Z</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeRequesterTypeAc">4</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeRequesterTypeDc">4</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          2017-06-29 10:46:05 PM
Event ID:      42
Task Category: (64)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: Button or Lid
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>42</EventID>
    <Version>3</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>64</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T05:46:05.993364100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22409</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="16764" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="Reason">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Flags">4</Data>
    <Data Name="TransitionsToOn">2</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          2017-06-29 10:46:05 PM
Event ID:      40
Task Category: (36)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Ceres
Description:
The driver \Driver\WSDScan for device SWD\DAFWSDProvider\urn:uuid:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c9740fd/uri:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c9740fd/ScannerService stopped the power transition.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>40</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>36</Task>
    <Opcode>35</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-30T05:46:05.992397700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22408</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6364" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DriverNameLength">15</Data>
    <Data Name="DriverName">\Driver\WSDScan</Data>
    <Data Name="InstanceNameLength">120</Data>
    <Data Name="InstanceName">SWD\DAFWSDProvider\urn:uuid:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c9740fd/uri:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c9740fd/ScannerService</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not normal. A PC or laptop has a clock (actually, multiple clocks) backed by a battery, separate from the main power battery. [image: Laptop with coin cell] Since this also may be used for CMOS backup, it could very well cause loss of time sync, precipitate a BSOD, or even prevent booting, if dead.

You don't mention the model of the laptop, so you'll need to look up the service manual to access, test and possibly replace this battery (or simple cell). Some fit in holders, other have an attached cord, or in worst cases, are soldered in place. In most cases, it's an easy fix, just requiring removal of many, sometimes hidden screws to open the laptop case. Download that manual to find 'em all.

Comment: thanks, I thought about it but forgot to add the following after fightining with the formatting of the code block. I added an UPDATE to the answer now. It reads "This laptop is less than 1 year old, so I don't think the CMOS battery is low. Sure, I could have gotten a bad battery, but that would cause the HW clock to drift, not the system clock."

Comment: Could still be a defective battery... you do not know how long the laptop was on the shelf, too. But i it's <1 year old, *take it back* because it should be under warranty.